# Is there a way to get max function to ignore nulls within a column in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Simply put, if I have a table with two columns (say people and height), I can use select max(height) from 'table' group by people and it will yield the largest height for any group of people_ignoring any nulls_.

If, however, I have a table with more columns (height_1, height_2, height_3, etc.) and I want to simply reproduce that table with a new column showing the maximum height (height_1, height_2, height_3, max_height), I would intuitvely like to put.

```
select
  height_1,
  height_2,
  height_3,
  max(height_1, height_2, height_3) as max_height
from 'table'
```

but used this way, max seems to behave differently, returning null if *any* of the arguments are null.

Is there some form of use which will get it to behave the way it does when aggregating a column, and ignore null values?, even when aggregating single values across a range of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```sql
SELECT height_1
     , height_2
     , height_3
     , max(ifnull(height_1, 0), ifnull(height_2, 0), ifnull(height_3, 0)) AS max_height
FROM "table"
```

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question, is there a way to do the same with min()? the problem here being that replacing nulls with '0' would give a false impression from the set {2,4,null,5,null,7} that the minimum was 0 when in fact the minimum non-null value is 2.

Comment: @Isaacson Just use a larger-than-possible number for `min()`, and a smaller-than-possible one for `max()` (And check if your select returned that number to handle cases of all values being null).